# Forbidden 403 GET JSON data remote REST service - Sharepoint hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, rest, web-services

I've been trying to follow [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179895%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but I'm getting the following exception:

> An exception occurred while processing the request - Forbidden 403, Access to example.com is denied. Sharepoint is currently configured to block intranet calls.

I have specified remote endpoints. I am using the SP.webproxy.

I'm using the following code:

JavaScript:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "../_api/SP.WebProxy.invoke",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(
            {
                "requestInfo": {
                    "__metadata": { "type": "SP.WebRequestInfo" },
                    "Url": "https://example.com",
                    "Method": "GET",
                    "Headers": {
                        "results": [{
                            "__metadata": { "type": "SP.KeyValue" },
                            "Key": "Accept",
                            "Value": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                            "ValueType": "Edm.String"
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }),
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-Mifos-Platform-TenantId": "default",
        "Authorization": "Basic randomletters",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    }
```

Appmanifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--Created:randomnumbers-->
<App xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest"
     Name="SPRestTest"
     ProductID="{randomletters}"
     Version="1.0.0.0"
     SharePointMinVersion="16.0.0.0"
>
  <Properties>
    <Title>SPRestTest</Title>
    <StartPage>~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}</StartPage>
  </Properties>

  <AppPrincipal>
    <Internal />
  </AppPrincipal>
      <RemoteEndpoints>
      <RemoteEndpoint Url="https://example.com" />
      </RemoteEndpoints>
</App>
```

### Update

It does work when I'm using the guide, to "services.odata.org" service, but when I'm trying to do the same thing towards my company's service, it doesn't work.

Do I have to do something more than adding `Authorization : basic randomletters` header in order to communicate with a https://example.com website? Because that's the only difference I can see: the one that gives me an error uses SSL

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid of "Sharepoint is currently configured to block intranet calls." errors

You can run the following SharePoint PowerShell commands

```
$farm=get-spfarm
$farm.properties.disableintranetcalls=$false
$farm.properties.disableintranetcallsfromapps=$false
$farm.Update()
```